# React and Django: CSRF Token is not set on production, and especially for create method

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django

on development, the csrf cookie used to be set normally if it is not in available in application tab in dev tool, however on production, whenever i try to create a new post, it tells me " `CSRF Failed: CSRF token from the 'X-Csrftoken' HTTP header has incorrect length.`"
however, the plot-twist here, is that with other post requests such as when you login, or signup, it works perfectly and fine, so i figured it seems to be a problem with `create` method in django (BUT with login , even though login works perfectly fine, and that i am logged in using session based authentication, it seem like session_id and csrf are invisible in application tab?

[image]

I assume it is because the website is on production and for security reasons, it wont show the session_id there.

However, whenever i try to look at network tab after i try to create a post and fail, it looks like `x-csrftoken` is `undefined`

[image]

but, there is another key called `cookie` which includes both `csrftoken` and `session_id`

[image]

please note that this only occur on production, i never faced such issue on development server, and look at settings.py code after the view code for more clarification (I added https://somedomain.com for the domain that need a csrf token allowed)

views.py:

```py
class CheckAuthenticated(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Response("Authenticated")
        else:
            return Response("Not Authenticated",status=401)
    
class PostView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializer.PostSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = models.Post.objects.all()
        return queryset
    
    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def create(self,request):
        authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication]
        permissions_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        post = serializer.PostSerializer(data=request.data)
        if post.is_valid():
            title = post.data['title']
  
            description = post.data['description']
    
            models.Post.objects.create(title=title,description=description,user=User.objects.first())
            return Response("post created successfully.")
        return Response("post creation failed.")
```

Now in frontend:

```js
let handleSubmit = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(Cookies.get('csrftoken'))
        axios.post('https://somedomain.com/posts/',post,{withCredentials:true,headers:{'X-CSRFToken':Cookies.get('csrftoken')}}).then((res)=>{
            console.log(res.data)
        }).catch((e)=>{
            console.log(e.response.data)
            console.log(Cookies.get('csrftoken'))
        })
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/').then((res)=>{
            setPostList(res.data)
        })
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/csrf/',{headers:{Authorization:null},withCredentials:true})

    },[])
```

settings.py code:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN = '*'
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS = '*'
ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS = '*'

'''
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

CSRF_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
'''
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Strict'  




CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [ "http://127.0.0.1:3000",'http://127.0.0.1:8000','https://somedomain.com/']

SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 60

CUSTOM_HEADERS = (
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
    'Token',
    'User-Type'
)
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = default_headers + CUSTOM_HEADERS
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'none'
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to answer this question , Basically the frontend is served on a different subdomain, so the cookie samesite rule need to be set to `None`, in `settings.py`: change `CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Strict'`  to `CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'`

also if you are using Session Based Authentication (which require a csrf token for post requests by default, [read the docs here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication)) dont forget to add:
`SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'`  in `settings.py`